# Angular2 and lodash...Cannot find name

Tags: angular, lodash

Angular2 and lodash...why so much drama?  I mean really...

Below is how I install

```
npm install --save lodash
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

UPDATE:

I followed thus blog and did this [angular2-and-lodash-cannot-find-name](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/angular2-error-cannot-find-name-many-and-namespace-_-issues-with-lodash-in-angular2-application-using-typescript/):
         npm install @types/lodash@ts2.0 --save-dev

It worked.  Only errors is with:

node_modules/@types/jasmine

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:40:37 
A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:40:45 
Cannot find name 'keyof'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:40:51 
'=' expected.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:42:45 
A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:42:55 
Cannot find name 'keyof'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:42:61 
'=' expected.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:58:41 
Cannot find name 'Partial'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:99:21 
Cannot find name 'Partial'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:99:34 
Cannot find name 'Partial'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts:241:12 
Duplicate identifier '_'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts:241:15 
Cannot find namespace '_'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts:243:24 
Cannot find name 'Partial'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts:245:18 
Duplicate identifier '_'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts:362:38 
Cannot find namespace '_'.
```

Comment: Check `typings.json` to see if this is your lodash
`"lodash": "registry:npm/lodash#4.0.0+20160305082308"`
If not change to that commit of lodash , 4.14.0 is giving the errors that you see.

Comment: No its not in the file

Comment: This is most likely because of the package version , try lowering the package for lodash in it's types

Comment: what is your `lodash` version? what is your `typescript` version? what is the exact `angular` version?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your `package.json` file to use this:

```
@types/jasmine@2.5.41 // Or 2.5.38
```

And it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It could happens cause of mismatch your `typescript` version with `lodash` version or `angular` version.

- `angular 2.x` running with `typescript 2.0.x`
- `angular 4.x` running with `typescript 2.2.x`

So first make sure that it is correct ^.

Then, make sure that your `lodash` version is compatible with your `typescript` version.

p.s
and one more small thing(not causing any of your issues) - it is better to `install @types/lodash --save-dev` as it just `@types` definition module.

Answer (score 1):

Add this snippet to your angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js" //make changes accordingly
      ],
```

In Component, Just add declare portion just after import section and use lodash normally.

```
import {EventsService} from '../../core/broadcast-event/broadcaster';
declare var _: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing lodash into your component?
`import * as _ from 'lodash'`

The above will import all of LoDash, so if you're concerned about chunk size, you'll want to specify whichever operators you're actually going to be using.

But importing as `_` should automatically pick up on the @types.